# How to make Tab pages' widths fit into the TabControl's width

Tags: c#, width, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a TabControl with two tab pages.

[image]

How can I make the tab pages fit into the width of the TabControl like shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

I tried with the following line of code but it does not work either.

```
tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.FillToRight;
```

Answer (score 9):

First, set your tabControl1 size mode:

```
tabControl1.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed;
```

Then you have to recalculate width of the tab page header:

```
tabControl1.ItemSize = new Size(tabControl1.Width / tabControl1.TabCount, 0);
```

Pay attention: 1. value 0 means that height will be default. 2. Recalculate item size after you had added tab page to tab control. Consider what happens when you resize the control.

Comment: If you use the full width the 'spin control' scroller will appear, subtract 1px from the new width to prevent this.

Comment: this doesn't work because you might have 1 extra pixel or one pixel less then the size of the control due to integer division

Answer (score 1):

Contributing based on Jarek's answer. If you want tabs widths to change dynamically as you resize the TabControl as well, you can achieve this by implementing this on the TabControl Resize Event:

```
private bool doNotExecuteResizeEventAgain = true;
private void Tab_Control_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(doNotExecuteResizeEventAgain)
     {
        int tabWidth = ((int)(tab_Control.Width/tab_Control.TabPages.Count)) - 1;
        doNotExecuteResizeEventAgain = false;
        tab_Control.ItemSize = new Size(tabWidth, tab_Details.ItemSize.Height);
        doNotExecuteResizeEventAgain = true;
     }
}
```

The use of the variable `doNotExecuteResizeEventAgain` is because the ItemSize calls again the event Resize, so in order to stop it from cycling, I added that flag.

Answer (score 0):

Use SizeMode on the TabControl: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.sizemode.aspx

Comment: As the OP mentioned this does not work. Missing from the docs is "This is only applicable to tab controls with **more than one row**. "

Answer (score -4):

this is illegal way to solve this kind of issue

Increase the padding (X,Y)
X 100 // represent some allowed figures
Y 3  // represent some allowed figure.