# Make Tab pages' widths fit into the TabControl's width

Tags: html, css, vb.net

I want to make these tabs have a custom size

[image]

so that all the tabs have the same size like this:

[image]

I know I need code, but where should I place the code? In my Form1.vb because there is where I placed the "TabControl" or in the Tab.vb?

What do you think and what code should I use?

Comment: http://dotnetrix.co.uk/tabcontrol.htm has quite a lot of code samples for customizing a tab control.

Comment: "[How to make tab pages fit into the tabcontrol's width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305457/how-to-make-tab-pages-widths-fit-into-the-tabcontrols-width)"